# Overwrite/Update the existing image file in the folder

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using a webcam to capture an image and place it to picturebox and save the image to my project folder and get the image path then save to sql database. The problem is i do not know how i gonna update/overwrite the existing file

NOTE: My data is bind in datagridview when i click the cell the image will be retrieved on another form, so basically it based on the ID.

Here's what i've tried to achieve that

```
private void BtnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (picCapturedImage.Image != null)
        {
            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(picCapturedImage.Image))
            {
                bitmap.Save(Common.CustomerPath, ImageFormat.Png);
                _updCustomer.picCustomerImage.Image = Image.FromFile(Common.CustomerPath);
            }
        }
        Close();
    }
```

When i run this code it replace the image of User.Png not the capture image(Image1, Image2, etc)
User.Png is my default image when user doesn't want to browse or capture an image

Here's the code for saving the image in the project folder

I used loop to avoid overwriting the image in the project folder, so when i saved the image

> Image0, Image1, Image2, etc

```
if (picCapturedImage.Image != null) {
            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(picCapturedImage.Image))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
                {
                    var fileName = $@"..\..\Resources\Photos\Image{i}.png";

                    if (!File.Exists(fileName)) {
                        bitmap.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png);
                        Common.CustomerPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, $@"..\..\Resources\Photos\Image{i}.png"));
                        _regCustomer.picCustomerImage.Image = Image.FromFile(Common.CustomerPath);
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        Close();
```

Here's the code where i save the path

```
 public class Common
 {
    public static string CustomerPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"..\..\Resources", "User.png"));
 }
```

Here's the code for retrieving the image path

```
_updCustomer.picCustomerImage.Image = Image.FromFile(customer.ImagePath);
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain also what happens when you try to run this code

Comment: Sorry i will update that, i forgot

Comment: CustomerPath is initialized with a fixed path with the _user.png_ image. If you never save a new image then you will always retrieve that initial file. All in all I think you should not use the same variable to hold two different things. One is the default, one is the current value for the current user. You should work on this second variable changing its value whenever the user changes.

Comment: Fix that but i get an error of GDI+